On fundamental solutions of parabolic PDEs
Let $U$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the PDE in $U \times [0, T] \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$, given by
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \rho(x, t) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Delta\rho(x, t) + \langle \nabla F(x), \nabla\rho(x, t)\rangle + \rho(x, t) \Delta F(x),\quad (x, t) \in U \times I,\\
\rho(x, 0) = \delta(x_0),\quad x \in U.
\end{cases}
$$
where $\nabla$ is the gradient with respect to $x$, $\Delta$ is the Lapacian with respect to $x$, $\alpha > 0$, $F$ is a $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function.
I assume that there exists a solution (in the space of distributions) to the above PDE.
I need to conclude that for any $t > 0$, $\rho(x, t)$ is such that $\int_X \rho(x, t)\, dx = 0$ for any subset $X \subset U$ of measure $0$. I.e. I would like to know that the solution is absolutely continuous for every $t>0$.
Are there any good references/ anyone has a proof for this?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Don't you mean $\int_X \rho(x,t)dx = 0$ for any subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ of measure non $0$?

No, my question is about subsets of measure zero

but isn't the integral over a $0$-measure set automatically $0$?

@LucasCândido Not necessarily, since $\rho$ starts out as a $\delta$ function. In particular, for elliptic PDEs like Laplace's equation, the Green's function will not satisfy the desired property because of a singularity. For parabolic PDEs, it is true, but it indeed requires a proof.

I guess the assumption is something like the existence of a solution in the a space of measures (or distributions), and the goal is to show that this measure (or distribution) is absolutely continuous (or regular) for positive times. But this should really be made clearer in the question.

@MaoWao exactly, thank you for pointing it out.

I also wanted to find a reference for this. The well-posedness of a linear parabolic PDE is used everywhere to prove the existence of solutions to the initial value problem of a nonlinear parabolic PDE (such as the Ricci flow, mean curvature flow, etc.). The best (only?) reference I could find is Avner Friedman's book. https://store.doverpublications.com/products/9780486466255

I would add that the existence and uniqueness of a solution that is smooth for $t > 0$ when the initial data is a measure with finite mass is a straightforward consequence of the theorem for smooth initial data and estimates for positive time in terms of the $L^1$ norm of the initial data.
